# Firefox page-worker API

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there a way to enable cookies, so that I can perform logins using the page-worker API? 
This is about how my code looks like:

```
var pageWorkers = require("sdk/page-worker");

pageWorkers.Page({
  contentURL: asdasd.com/login.php?id=xxxxxx&pwd=yyyyyyy
  contentScript: "self.postMessage(document.body.innerHTML)",
  contentScriptWhen: "ready",
  onMessage: function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  }
});
pageWorkers.Page({
  contentURL: asdasd.com/site_that_is_only_visible_if_loged_in.php
  contentScript: "self.postMessage(document.body.innerHTML)",
  contentScriptWhen: "ready",
  onMessage: function(msg) {
    console.log(msg); 
  }
});
```

The second console.log() tells me that I'm not loged in. That's why I'm assuming that the login cookies are not saved. 
If I open the login link and the other one in firefox manually, it works fine. The add-on doesn't seem to be able to do ut. :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to reuse the same PageWorker, rather than creating a second one:

```
var pagecount = 0; 

var pageWorker = require("sdk/page-worker").Page({
  contentURL: "http://asdasd.com/login.php?id=xxxxxx&pwd=yyyyyyy",
  contentScript: "self.postMessage(document.body.innerHTML)",
  contentScriptWhen: "ready",
  onMessage: function(msg) {

    console.log("html: "+msg);
    if (++pagecount == 1) 
        loadSecondPage();
  }
});

function loadSecondPage() {
    pageWorker.contentURL =
       "http://asdasd.com/site_that_is_only_visible_if_loged_in.php";
}
```